# Create a non abstract parent with a URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a simple form that can be used to initiate a forecast request. I created this as a parent state `requests` (Initiate Forecast).

Desired behavior

1. When a request is submitted, that immediate request is shown in a child state (View Status) as most recent request. This `View Status` state will also hold a grid of all past requests, meaning I will be refreshing the grid with data every time this state is invoked.
2. Both parent and child states are navigable from a sidebar menu.
3. So, if a user clicks on parent (Initiate Forecast), he should be able to see only the form to submit a request. If a user directly clicks on the 'View Status'(child), then he should be able to see both the form and the grid of requests.

> app.js

```
function statesCallback($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('requests', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: 'initiateforecasting.html',
        controller: 'requestsInitiateController'
      },
      'content': {
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
      }
    },
    params: {
      fcId: null,
      fcIndex: null
    }
  })
  .state('requests.viewStatus', {
    url: '/ViewStatus',
    templateUrl: 'viewstatus.html',
    controller: 'requestsStatusController'
  });
}

var requestsApp = angular.module('requestsApp', ['ui.router']);
requestsApp.config(['$stateProvider', statesCallback]);
requestsApp.run(['$state', function($state) {
  $state.go('requests');
}]);
```

[Plunker of my attempts so far](http://plnkr.co/edit/nzUWOGCj41SxkUCn4h1H).

This is all working for me as shown in the plunker, but I am doing it by not setting a URL to the parent. Having no URL for the parent state is allowing me to see both states. If I add a URL to parent state, then clicking on View Status link is not going anywhere (it stays on Initiate).

How do I change this so that I can have a URL for parent state and still retain the behaviour I need from the parent and child states as described above?

Note: I am fine without the URL for parent state in standalone sample code, but when I integrate this piece with backend code, having no URL fragment on the parent state is making an unnecessary request to the server. This is visible when I navigate to the child state and then go to the parent state. It effectively gives the impression of reloading the page which I think is unnecessary and can be avoided if a URL can be set to the parent state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall not directly write url when using ui.router, try like this:

```
<a ui-sref="requests.viewStatus">View Status</a>
```

You are writing state name in `ui-sref` directive and it automatically resolves url. It's very comfortable because you can change urls any time and it will not break navigation.

Comment: This worked, but also I had to use `/requests` as URL for the parent state.